# Etymology: When did the words "idea" and "concept" become interchangeable?

Tags: etymology

The word "idea" used to be connected with Plato and refer to a thing's "ideal" (thus, they share the same root). Does anyone know how this word come to be conflated with the word "concept", which refers to a mental image?

Comment: Have you done any research on the etymologies?

Comment: Well, I asked because it seems to be entangled in a larger debate between realism and nominalism in philosophy. I'm afraid I don't know where to look to see at what point nominalism started to win, and was hoping a history of the word's usage might help. Every tool I find simply says it started to change, but not which thinkers or what movement caused it. Happy to know of a tool that could do this!

Comment: If you want to examine it through a philosophical lens, the Philosophy SE might be more helpful.

Comment: Thank you, I will try them if this question turns out not to be edifying for others on this particular SE

Comment: Without showing some kind of research, I imagine this question will be closed here.